# Выделить в тег small дробные число прайса

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно с помощью JavaScript взять в тег small дробные число, то есть копейки
пример как должен быть

```
<p class="price">630.<small>01</small> ₽</p>
```

2 последние цифры, кроме символа рубль  (₽)

```html
<p class="price">630.01 ₽</p>
    <p class="price">50.00 ₽</p>
    <p class="price">150.55 ₽</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let regexp = /((\.|\s|,)[0-9]{1,2})/;
document.querySelectorAll(".price").forEach(elem => {
  elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(regexp, '<small>$1</small>')
});
```

```html
<p class="price">630 01 ₽</p>
<p class="price">50.00 ₽</p>
<p class="price">150,55 ₽</p>
```

```js
let regexp = /(\.[0-9]{1,2})/;
document.querySelectorAll(".price").forEach(elem => {
  elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(regexp, '<small>$1</small>')
});
```

```html
<p class="price">630.01 ₽</p>
<p class="price">50.00 ₽</p>
<p class="price">150.55 ₽</p>
```

Comment: а можно сделать так, чтоб не зависело от точки? <p class="price">630 01 ₽</p>

Comment: А как дробную часть определять? Можно запятую сделать, либо точку в регулярном выражении

Comment: то есть определить дробную часть  по 2 последним цифрам, после обработки добавить символ рубл. сайт делается на движке, думаю, нужно убрать точки, а копейки показать маленькими

Comment: Ок, сейчас отредактирую

Comment: Сделал, работает если есть точка, запятая или пробел

Comment: спасибо добрый человек

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.price').forEach(el => {
    let text = el.textContent;
    let indexOfPoint = text.indexOf('.');
    let result = `${text.substr(0, indexOfPoint + 1)}<small>${text.substr(indexOfPoint + 1, 2)}</small>${text.substr(indexOfPoint + 3)}`;
    
    el.innerHTML = result;
})
```

```css
.price small {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="price">630.01 ₽</p>
<p class="price">50.00 ₽</p>
<p class="price">150.55 ₽</p>
```

Comment: Похоже на армию ботов на stackoverflow, интересно)

Comment: @DanilApsadikov тоже подумал об этом. либо я кому-то сильно понравился )))